# TextBox inside an Ellipse WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, ellipse

I am trying to add filtering to my WPF app, so I figured that I want to have an ellipse, and inside it will be a TextBox whose Text will be bound to a `FilterText` property in my `ViewModel`.

What I have tried:

```
<TextBox
      Width="30"
      Height="30">
      <TextBox.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                  <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
                        <ContentPresenter
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              Content="{Binding FilterText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                              TextElement.Foreground="Black" />
                  </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
      </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```

I took this from the same example, but with Label.

This displays the ellipse, but no TextBox inside it.

How can I create an ellipse WITH a TextBox?

Comment: A ContentPresenter does not provide support for editing. Use `<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />` instead and bind the TextBox's Text property. For details see [TextBox Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: It's also unclear why the Ellipse needs to be in the Template at all. You may as well just put an Ellipse and an ordinary TextBox in a common Grid cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by wrapping the `TextBox` inside a `Border` and setting the `Border`'s `CornerRadius`:

```
<Border
       Width="30"
       Height="30"
       BorderBrush="Black"
       BorderThickness="1"
       CornerRadius="30">
       <TextBox
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
              Background="Transparent" //important to lose the TextBox look
              BorderBrush="Transparent" //important to lose the TextBox look
              BorderThickness="0" //important to lose the TextBox look
              Text="{Binding FilterText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Grid>
    <Ellipse Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding FilterText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```